# How to create a NDK AMediaMuxer?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to convert my java Media code in **JNI**.
In **java**, we create a mediaMuxer with the absolute path of the target file

```
MediaMuxer(@NonNull String path, @Format int format)
```

when the JNI version of the muxer use a file descriptor.

```
AMediaMuxer* AMediaMuxer_new(int fd, OutputFormat format);
```

One way is to use assets, but the asset is like ressource files: read only. So it is not the good way to do that.

What is the good way to create a fileDescriptor and pass it to the JNI muxer constructor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible - it is overkilling to obtain file descriptor on java side and then pass it to native code. Much easier is to pass output file name and open file in native code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <jni.h>

void my_jni_func(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring filename) {
    const char* c_filename = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename)
    int output_fd = open(c_filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, filename, c_filename);

    /* Check output_fd for validity, create muxer, and write streams */

    close(output_fd); /* close file when you've finished with muxer */
}
```